# How to efficiently return the max possible integer with a given number of digits

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

For example, what would be the most efficient way to get say `999` if given an `n` that equals 3 for instance.

This is what I have got right now but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

```
public static int largestPossibleNumber(int numDigits) {
  return Integer.parseInt(new String(new char[numDigits]).replace("\0", "9"));
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  System.out.println(largestPossibleNumber(i));
}
```

**Output:**

```
9
99
999
9999
99999
```

Comment: If it helps, it's 10 to the N, minus 1.

Comment: if you are looking for the fastest method, you can precompute an array `{0, 9, 99, 999, ..., 99999999 }` then take the value by index

Comment: Ah... my brains not the best in the morning... thx @khelwood

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I presume to fill out the array you would use te same idea as khelwood's ?

Comment: @LogicNewbie: I suggest *hardcoding* `private static int[] data = {0, 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999, 99999999};`

Comment: `"999999999".substring(0, numberOfDigits)`. Yes, I know it gives a string not an `int`. If you need to parse it into one, it may not be runtime efficient anymore, but will still be efficient to read, so whether you want it, depends on what you mean by “efficient”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just **8** valid answers, so you can *hardcode* them:

```
  private static int[] s_Numbers = {
    0, 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999, 99999999};

  private static int largestPossibleNumber(int n) {
    return s_Numbers[n];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for **the most** efficient way. It's rather hard to prove that some way is *the most* efficient - it would require implementing and benchmarking multiple methods at least.

But here's a pretty fast way to do this — just create a `Map`, or use a `switch`, see below. 
This works because the size of an `int` is fixed. Note however, that this method won't extend to, say, `BigInteger`s.

```
public static int largestPossibleNumber(final int numDigits) {
    switch (numDigits) {
        case 1: return 9;
        case 2: return 99;
        case 3: return 999;
        case 4: return 9999;
        case 5: return 99999;
        case 6: return 999999;
        case 7: return 9999999;
        case 8: return 99999999;
        case 9: return 999999999;
        case 10: return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int largestPossibleNumber(int n) {
    return (int) (Math.pow(10.0, n)) -1;
}
```

Comment: Floating-point exponentiation _isn't efficient_, and this will yield wrong result for the input value of `10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int largestPossibleNumber(int numDigits) {
  return (int) (Math.pow(10, numDigits)) - 1;
}
```

Comment: This tends to fail so easily if the number of digits gets a bit larger, should there not be some guard code or at least a javadoc defining the applicable range of `numbDigits`?